How can i "add" additional Data (Classification-Codes) to an existing Field
I have build a model which should representate our Products at work. Our products are different sorts of luminaires. Some of these with different variations like different colour-temperature, different housing-colour, different power, sensors or dimmable.
at the moment my model looks (a little shortend) like this
    class ProductID(models.Model):
        product_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
        base_model = models.BooleanField(default=True)
        active = models.BooleanField(default=True, choices=CHOICES)
        possible_as_option = models.BooleanField(default=False, choices=CHOICES)
        product_variant_data = models.ForeignKey('ProductVariantData', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
        ...
    
    class ProductVariantData(models.Model):
        short_text = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
        packaging_unit = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1)])
        guarantee = models.IntegerField()
        product = models.ForeignKey('Product', null=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
        ...
    
    class Product(models.Model):
        enec = models.BooleanField(default=False)
        ce = models.BooleanField(default=True)
        min_ambient_temperature = models.IntegerField()
        max_ambient_temperature = models.IntegerField()
        ip_code = models.ForeignKey(IPCode, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
        ik_code = models.ForeignKey(IKCode, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
        dimensions = models.ForeignKey(Dimensions)
        cutout_dimensions = models.ForeignKey(CutoutDimensions, null=True)
        product_type = models.ForeignKey(ProductType, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
        ....
    
    class LEDData(models.Model):
        led_changeable = models.BooleanField(default=True)
        average_lifespan = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
        dimmable = models.BooleanField(default=False)
        voltage = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, null=False)
        flicker_metric = models.DecimalField(max_digits=2, decimal_places=1, null=True)
        stroboscopic_effect_metric = models.DecimalField(max_digits=2, decimal_places=1, null=True)
    
    class LEDData(models.Model):
        average_lifespan = models.IntegerField()
        dimmable = models.BooleanField(default=True)
        voltage = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, null=False)
        flicker_metric = models.DecimalField(max_digits=2, decimal_places=1, null=True)
        stroboscopic_effect_metric = models.DecimalField(max_digits=2, decimal_places=1, null=True)
    
    class Luminaire(models.Model):
        product = models.OneToOneField(Product, primary_key=True)
        control_gear_included = models.BooleanField(default=True)
        external_control_gear = models.BooleanField(default=True)
        control_gear_changeable = models.BooleanField(default=True)
        control_gears = models.ManyToManyField('ControlGear', through='LuminaireControlGearDetails')
        led_data = models.ForeignKey(LEDData)
        lighting_technology = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=LightingTechnology, default=LightingTechnology.LED)
        ...
    
    class LightColour(models.Model):
        colour = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    
    class PhotometricData(models.Model):
        luminaire = models.ForeignKey(Luminaire)
        lum_flux = models.IntegerField()
        cri = models.IntegerField(validators=[MaxValueValidator(100), MinValueValidator(-100)])
        power_details = models.ForeignKey('PowerDetails')
        ldt_file = models.FileField(upload_to='data/ldt_files/', null=True)
        light_curve = models.FileField(upload_to='data/light_curve/', null=True)
        reference_settings = models.BooleanField(default=False)
        colour_consistency = models.IntegerField(validators=[MaxValueValidator(7), MinValueValidator(1)])
        colour_temperature = models.ForeignKey(ColourTemperature, on_delete=models.PROTECT,null=True, blank=True)
        light_colour = models.ForeignKey()
    
    class EmergencyLighting(models.Model):
        product = models.OneToOneField(Product, primary_key=True)
        ....
    
    class ControlGear(models.Model):
        product = models.OneToOneField(Product, primary_key=True)
        ....

my "problem" now: We want to classify our product-data with the ETIM-System (for example the link for the ceiling light )
this classification has a system with one class per product-group (like "EC002892" for "Ceiling-/wall luminaire") featurecodes and valuecodes. Some featurecodes need an integer, some an boolean and others have some values with an valuecode where you have to choose ONE.
One example for a Boolean Property (they call it Logical):
Code "EF000137" - Description "Dimmable" - Type "Logical" -> this should be "mapped" to my dimmable-BooleanField in the LEDData class.
Other example for a Property with valuecode (they call it Alphanumeric)
Code "EF009350" - Description "Colour of light" - Type "Alphanumeric" -> this should be "mapped" to my colour-CharField in the LightColour class.
First i tried a seperate class for all the properties but i have no clue how i referentiate to this from all other classes. a one many-to-many-field in every class looks wrong on so many ways.. PLUS...building forms later would be not fun..
    class ETIMClass(models.Model):
        code = models.CharField(max_length=25)
        short_description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        version = models.IntegerField()
        etim_feature_codes = models.ManyToManyField('ETIMFeatureCode', through='ETIMFeatureCodeAdditions')

    class ETIMFeatureCodeAdditions(models.Model):
        etim_class = models.ForeignKey('ETIMClass', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
        etim_feature_code = models.ForeignKey('ETIMFeatureCode', on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True)
        order = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    class ETIMFeatureType(models.Model):
        etim_feature_type = models.CharField(max_length=30)
        short = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    
    class ETIMFeatureCode(models.Model):
        code = models.CharField(max_length=20)
        value_codes = models.ManyToManyField('ETIMValueCode')
        feature_type = models.ForeignKey(ETIMFeatureType, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    
    class ETIMValueCode(models.Model):
        code = models.CharField(max_length=20)
        text = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    
    class PropertyType(models.Model):
        type = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    
    class Property(models.Model):
        text = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)
        etim_code = models.ForeignKey(ETIMFeatureCode, null=True, blank=True,
                                      on_delete=models.PROTECT)
        type = models.ForeignKey(PropertyType, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=False)
    
    class ProductProperty(models.Model):
        product_id = models.ForeignKey('ProductID', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
        property = models.ForeignKey(Property, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=False)
        char_value = models.CharField()
        int_value = models.IntegerField()
        datetime_value = models.DateTimeField()
        bool_value = models.BooleanField()
        decimal_value = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=3)
        etim_value_code = models.ForeignKey(ETIMValueCode, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True)
    
        @property
        def value(self):
            if self.product_property.type == "integer":
                return self.int_value
            elif self.product_property.type == "char":
                return self.char_value
                ...

last idea. i save the "path" to every field which i need for the specific feature and value-code in another class and use getattr to lookup the specific field but this is also sh....
At the End i want to export these Data to an XML-File with this (shortend) schema
    <REFERENCE_FEATURE_SYSTEM_NAME>ETIM-7.0</REFERENCE_FEATURE_SYSTEM_NAME>
    <REFERENCE_FEATURE_GROUP_ID>EC000000</REFERENCE_FEATURE_GROUP_ID>
    <FEATURE>
        <FNAME>-</FNAME>
        <FVALUE>-</FVALUE>
    </FEATURE>

For every classified product there must be ALL feature/value pairs in a predefined order in this file. OK, i can do it completely by hand but if there is a better solution i would go with this.
